# How to plot quiver arrows over x-axis and y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Currently my plot made with matplotlib looks like figure 1, as you can see on the x-axis, the half of my arrow is being covered by the axis.

I would like it so the entire arrow is shown as in Figure 2.

Here is the relevant part of my code, X_fine and Y_fine have same range as X and Y but with more bins.

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(arrow_csf_centre, arrow_precip_centre)
X_fine, Y_fine = np.meshgrid(arrow_csf_centre_fine, arrow_precip_centre_fine)

plt.contourf(X_fine, Y_fine, np.transpose(counts2_fine), 30)
plt.quiver(X,
           Y,
           np.transpose(arrow_dirs[:,:,0]),
           np.transpose(arrow_dirs[:,:,1]), 
           angles='xy', 
           scale_units='xy',
           scale=1,
           pivot='mid')
```

**Figure1 - my plot**
[image: Figure 1 - my plot]

**Figure2 - goal plot**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add: `clip_on=False` in `plt.quiver`

This should do it.

Related:
[How do I let my matplotlib plot go beyond the axes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912206/how-do-i-let-my-matplotlib-plot-go-beyond-the-axes)